# MySQL update returns 0 rows affected while select returns results

Tags: mysql, select, sql-update, innodb

```
select * from t_circle
where status = 0 and author_phone = 13511111111
and id in (
1,
2,
3
)
;
```

returns 3 rows with status of 0.

But the following update query with same conditions returns 0 rows affected:

```
udpate t_circle set status = 2
where status = 0 and author_phone = 13511111111
and id in (
1,
2,
3
);
```

Is there a reason for this? I have tried start transaction and commit, but still 0 rows affected. Other questions' answers suggest to run select first and make sure the rows are changed since if new value == old value, it is considered affected. I have excluded these 2 possibilities.

Note: this issue is found in our production server(Yeah I know I shouldn't but I have to) with InnoDB engine. I could modify the contents in GUI client like DBeaver and click save and the changes take effect, but not with sql statements. I wonder if it has anything to do with my account authorization?

**Resolved! It is because I misspelled UPDATE. When I use `mysql>` in command line, update with 'udpate' just gives `Query OK, 0 rows affected`. My mysql's version is 5.7**

Comment: I don't see how this is possible without the underlying data having changed in between the time the select and update were run.  Are you certain that you ran the select/update right next to each other _and_ that the underlying data was not being changed?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I even ran the select AFTER the update. And still the same 3 matching rows popped out.

Comment: What is the column type of `author_phone`?  Are you aware that `2147483647` is the largest value which can fit into a signed integer column in MySQL?

Comment: it is varchar, I added quotes to the phone number and tried again but nothing changed.

Comment: Does there exists some BEFORE UPDATE trigger on this table?

Comment: Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query and amend your question accordingly

Comment: @Akina, no, there are not any.

Comment: Try to reproduce the issue on [online fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0).

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. Some questions  - is this a simplified version of code, you say you can do this succesfully using dbbeaver - is that in production or development? Are you saying you cannot do this in both production and development? is production an exact mirror of development (data and codebase)

Comment: @P.Salmon Not just in dbeaver, navicat as well. As long as i dont run SQL, but modify the contents directly in GUI and click 'save' or 'apply'.

Comment: @P.Salmon I can change the database with GUI in production but not with command lines(F6) for production in Navicat

Comment: @P.Salmon It doesn't work in DBeaver's script tab either

Comment: not familiar with these ides or if they have a feature which will silently fail some sql commands , or what you mean by command lines(F6) , I would try to  run the code from mysql command line to take the ide out of the mix to establish if the ide(s) is at fault and blocking or hiding errors -seems unlikely I know - best try in  dev first.

Comment: @P.Salmon I just tried connecting with command line, and run sql update query. Still 0 rows affected.

Comment: In that case I'm out of ideas, such simple code should just work and does(I cannot reproduce your issue)

Comment: @P.Salmon Problem solved, I misspelled UPDATE. MySQL didn't complain about syntax error though, which is quite surprising.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Problem solved, I misspelled UPDATE. MySQL didn't complain about syntax error though, which is quite surprising.

Comment: @Akina Problem solved, I misspelled UPDATE. MySQL didn't complain about syntax error though, which is quite surprising.

Comment: Doh..couldn't see that myself..

Comment: That's not good if the tools you're using shows `0 rows affected` only without pointing out there's an error in the syntax - even if it just a typo. You may try other tools like [SQLyog Community](https://github.com/webyog/sqlyog-community/wiki/Downloads).

Comment: @fadlikidd it's not just the tools, even when I use `mysql>` in command line, update with 'udpate' just gives `Query OK, 0 rows affected`. My mysql's version is 5.7

Comment: omg, that's crazy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By comparing GUI generated sql queries when I change something in GUI and my own queries. I found out the reason is I misspelled `update` to `udpate`. Now I begin to wonder how could mysql not complain about syntax error and just returns with `0 rows affected`?

Well, at least now I know what to do when something odd happens.

Answer (score 0):

I know that there is something wrong with the user permission of your client

Comment: Permissions problem would produce according error message. There is no IGNORE option.